# Xubuntu don't boot

Tags: 12.04, boot, xubuntu

While booting display blinks twice and nothing happened.It seems that Xubuntu started but display shows nothing.Also when if i chose previous Linux versions or repair option in GRUB it boots normally.

Comment: If you solved this problem. Can you write it down and accept it to be the correct solution ?

Comment: No.Today I realized that Xubuntu don't boot only when I'm restarting a computer.So I need to turn off it and turn on again.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details it's hard to suggest anything but one thing you can do if you believe the system has already booted is switching to the first terminal by pressing

CTRL+ALT+F1 (to F6 if I remember correctly). CTRL is needed for when the xserver has already started.

Then you can start looking at log files if your system is already up.

Comment: so i don't know what happened but now it's loading normally.And i don't why.Anyway, thanks for answer

Comment: aaaaand problem comes back...I can't understand from what it depends.

Comment: Have you tried switching to the first (or other) terminal?

Comment: yes.and it didn't work, but i'm sure that system loaded, because when i pressed power-off button the hdd LED blinked and after ~1,5sec laptop turns off